# How can I format a specific string "05-Jan-2022 12:05 AM" to a date object in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, date, foundation

I've tried using this piece of code, works fine in playground but crashes the app in actual project.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm a"
    
    let dates = [
        "05-Jan-2022 12:00 AM",
        "11-Nov-2021 12:00 AM",
        "11-Nov-2021 12:00 AM",
        "08-Oct-2021 03:04 PM",
        "08-Oct-2021 12:00 AM",
        "30-Sep-2021 03:48 PM"
    ]
    
    dates.forEach { date in
        print(dateFormatter.date(from: date)!)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

- You have to set the locale to fixed `en_US_POSIX`
- 12 hr format is `hh`

  ```
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a"
  ```